Trouble Injecting ViewModel with Hilt in Android Kotlin App
I'm working on an Android app using Kotlin, Jetpack Compose, and Hilt for dependency injection. Despite following the recommended setup for Hilt, I keep encountering a runtime exception when trying to create an instance of my HomeViewModel. I've verified my Hilt setup in both the build.gradle files and within my code, yet the issue persists.
Exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class tech.diadem.luckydays.composeScreens.viewmodel.HomeViewModel


This exception is thrown despite having seemingly correctly set up my ViewModel, repository, and network service classes for Hilt injection.
HomeViewModel.kt:
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository_ 
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _userName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val userName: LiveData<String> = _userName

    fun fetchUserName(authToken: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = userRepository.getUserName(authToken)
            result.onSuccess {
                _userName.value = it.first?.userName ?: "Unknown"
            }.onFailure {
                _userName.value = "Error fetching user"
            }
        }
    }
}


UserRepository_.kt:
class UserRepository_ @Inject constructor(private val networkService: NetworkService) {
    suspend fun getUserName(authToken: String): Result<Pair<UserDetails?, Int>> {
        return networkService.fetchUserDetails(authToken)
    }
}


NetworkService.kt and NetworkModule.kt:
interface NetworkService {
    suspend fun fetchUserDetails(authToken: String): Result<Pair<UserDetails?, Int>>
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideNetworkService(@ApplicationContext context: Context): NetworkService {
        return VolleyNetworkService(context)
    }
}


Application Class:
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyLuckyDays_Hilt : Application()


build.gradle (Module):
Dependencies include Hilt, ViewModel, Kotlin, etc. (Note: Adjust this part based on your actual dependencies, focusing on Hilt and any potentially relevant libraries).
I've followed the Hilt documentation closely and reviewed my setup multiple times, but I can't identify what I'm missing or doing wrong that leads to the above exception.
Questions:
Is there any mistake in how I've set up Hilt for dependency injection in my ViewModel?
Could the problem lie in how I'm providing my NetworkService through Hilt, or in the way UserRepository_ is set up?
Are there additional debugging steps I could take to pinpoint the cause of this injection failure?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Since you haven't mentioned the code of your Activity and Fragment. I am assuming that you forgot to add @AndroidEntryPoint in your Activity and Fragments classes.
Just annotate your Activity and Fragment class with @AndroidEntryPoint and it should work. Check the following link:
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes
